# Generating a Poisson Random Variable. Let U_{1}, U_{2} be independent uniform (0, 1) random variables.

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

Generating a Poisson Random Variable. Let U_{1}, U_{2} be independent uniform (0, 1) random variables. (a) If X 1 =(- log(U) prime )/ lambda, show that X , is exponentially distributed with rate A.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: Your title suggests a question about the Poisson distribution, but the question is actually about an exponential distribution. Do you know how repeated exponential sampling can give you a Poisson sample?